# Selecting a post and all of its tags from two table with a single Query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables; one with post data and in the other each row has a tag and post id (FK).
Is it possible to select a post with all of its tags from these two tables with a single Query? How?

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide sample input and output data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you could turn around the query

```
SELECT * FROM post p 
INNER JOIN TABLE tag
ON tag.tag_id = p.tag_id
WHERE p.post_id=?
```

Though I don't think that this will be quicker than doing 2 separate queries

---

EDIT

The comments below think it is quicker to do a join rather than two separate query.

Comment: Yes, this is correct.  However: please never use the implicit-join (comma-separated `FROM` clause) syntax, as it's been deprecated on every major RDBMS.  And on every system I'm aware of, doing a (simple) `JOIN` (over a properly setup database) _will_ be faster than attempting to do 2 separate queries.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse . . . I agree with your comment for the most part.  Unfortunately, though, the comma has not been deprecated in most databases.  There are many reasons not to use it, but deprecation is not one of them.  Alas.

Comment: Good to know! I've edited it and will now use JOIN operators. Though some uni still give comma separated tables one way of doing joins ;)
Anyway thanks for the advice

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you have tables named posts(id, content) and tags(post_id, tag):

```
SELECT posts.id, posts.content, tags.tag FROM posts 
    LEFT JOIN tags ON tags.post_id = posts.id
WHERE posts.id = ?
```